# Update a Google sheet cell using document ID

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I often use code like this to update a cell on a google sheet:

```
var test="stuff for cell";

SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('A1').setValue(test);
```

I now find it necessary to access and update sheets for which I have the ID. Basically, I'm looking for something like this:

```
var test = "stuff for cell";

var ssID = '1234567';  
    
SpreadsheetApp.**getSpreadsheetByID(ssID)**.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('A1').
setValue(test);
```

I've looked everywhere, but can't seem to find this type of function. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i believe .openById() is what you're looking for.

SpreadsheetApp.***openById***(ssID).getSheetByName.....

Comment: That's it So obvious. Don't know why it was difficult for me to find.

Comment: No worries.  I think the word "open" is a bit misleading!